# Can the python shap package be used with MLNET models (or models that are not sklearn)?

Tags: python-3.x, ml.net, shap, ml.net-model-builder

Every example I've found using the Shap package demonstrates with models from sklearn. How would I extend this to an ML.Net model? Do I just need a score file, ground truth file and prediction file?

I've checked this documentation: https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overviews.html

Answer (score 0):

a very wild guess would be try to [convert idataview to dataframe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.idataviewextensions.todataframe?view=ml-dotnet-preview) and then call shap methods with [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)
tell me if it worked ;)